# PySpark to Batch JSON Documents

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large dataframe of time series data (~billion rows) in which I used pandas to generate from XML files. Next, I did a groupby on the unique ID fields in order to start writing batch JSON documents of size 'n' to a NoSQL database. Initially, wrote the code in pandas to do this, but does not scale, thus looking to apply Spark. Stuck on generating a batch size of every 'n' rows for each unique group to the db.  Here's what I have so far:

```
def transform_data(x):

    names = x.loc[0,'colNames'].split(',')
    df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(',') for i in x.loc[0,'data']],columns=names)

    # Convert to Spark DataFrame 
    d = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)

    # Convert dTim to DateTime & Sort
    d = d.withColumn("dTim",d['dTim'].cast(TimestampType()))
    d = d.sort('dTim')

    #ToDo: Create batches of size 'n' json files to write to document to database

df.groupby(['id']).apply(transform_data)
```

Note the number of columns varies per ID time series data

```
+--------------------+--------+-------+------------+
|                dTim|    ColA|   ColB|       ColC | 
+--------------------+--------+-------+------------+
|2017-01-05 11:09:...|       2|1448.00|     0.73838|               
|2017-01-05 11:10:...|       2|1437.00|     0.73636|           
|2017-01-05 11:10:...|       2|1428.00|     0.63531|         
|2017-01-05 11:10:...|       2|1483.03|     0.64536|      
|2017-01-05 11:10:...|       2|1488.03|     0.63937|    
+--------------------+--------+-------+------------+
```

Expected JSON output for batch size of 2:

```
{'id':'ABD',
 'data':[{
    'dTim':2017-01-05 11:09:...,
    'ColA':2,
    'ColB':1448.00,
    'ColC':0.73838
    },
    {
    'dTim':2017-01-05 11:10:...,
    'ColA':2,
    'ColB':1437.00,
    'ColC':0.73636
    }]
},
{'id':'ABD',
 'data':[{
    'dTim':2017-01-05 11:10:...,
    'ColA':2,
    'ColB':1428.00,
    'ColC':0.63531
    },
    {
    'dTim':2017-01-05 11:10:...,
    'ColA':2,
    'ColB':1483.03,
    'ColC':0.64536
    }]
},
{'id':'ABD',
 'data':[{
    'dTim':2017-01-05 11:10:...,
    'ColA':2,
    'ColB':1488.03,
    'ColC':0.63937
    }]
},
```

Comment: Why don't you go into a loop for a range of unique ID's, filter the dataframe where `id==i`,convert the dataframe in to JSON, reformat it if you like and post it to a NoSQL database?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function `grouped()` on each partition to do the batching.

```
val numParallelInserts = 10
val batchSize = 1000

new CoalescedRDD(sessions, numParallelInserts) mapPartitionsWithSplit { (split, iter) => Iterator((split, iter)) } foreach { case (split, iter) =>
val db = connect()

val sql = "INSERT INTO sessions (id, ts) VALUES (?, ?)"
val stmt = db.prepareStatement(sql)

iter.grouped(batchSize).zipWithIndex foreach { case (batch, batchIndex) =>
batch foreach { session =>
stmt.setString(1, session.id)
stmt.setString(2, TimestampFormat.print(session.ts))
stmt.addBatch()
}
stmt.executeBatch()
db.commit();
logInfo("Split " + (split+1) + "/" + numParallelInserts + " inserted batch " + batchIndex + " with " + batch.size + " elements")
}
db.close();
```

There is also a batchSize provided in the JDBC. For example i want to create a batch of 100 records for every insert.

```
dataFrame
    .write
    .mode(saveMode)
    .option("batchsize", 100)
    .jdbc(url, "tablename", new java.util.Properties())
```

[http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases](http://batchsize%20jdbc)